# Kotlin Val field not evaluating as expected

Tags: class, kotlin, variables

In my class i have the following field

```
private val COLOR_COFFEE = Color.parseColor("#6F4E37")
```

For some strange reason this is evaluated as 0.
If i perform the following test

```
fun test(){
  Log.d("test", "${COLOR_COFFEE} ${Color.parseColor("#6F4E37")}")
}
```

I get the output

```
D/test: 0 -9482697
```

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Is this being called from a constructor? Objects are partially initialized during execution of a constructor.

Comment: Yes - it's being used in init, that's quite frustrating, I guess the solution is to add it to companion object

Comment: Yeah, if it never uses `self` and is the same for every instance, then I recommend throwing it in a companion object.

Comment: Or perhaps even outside of the class, in the same file.

Comment: A top-level private property has a similar effect, and is often simpler.